# en JPA para una tabla intermedia, es mejor usar ManyToMany o dos OneToMany

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

estoy aprendiendo JPA y al momento de tener que crear una tabla intermedia con jpa, esta la opcion de usar ManyToMany o Crear la entidad de la tabla intermedia y usar OneToMany 2 veces para conectarla a las entidades que se relacionaran.

Mi duda es cual forma es mejor usar o cual es conveniente segun el caso.

pdt: si se usa el ManyToMany como se elimina un registro en la taba intermedia?

Comment: Bienvenido Wilder. Deberías evitar las preguntas que se basen en dar opiniones generales sobre un tema. Muestra el código que has  probado hasta ahora, para esa tarea concreta e indica los problemas que te pueden ocasionar y quisieras evitar. Pásate por el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)  y revisa los apartados sobre como [realizar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y como  [crear un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), así podrás obtener ayudas de calidad y ayudar a su vez a otras personas.

Comment: La mejor forma de preguntar es que definas un caso en concreto, una situación que hayas visto que te genere la duda, porque en la programación no existe algo como una regla que siempre se aplique todo depende del problema que quieras solucionar y la experiencia, lo mejor que aportes un ejemplo en código demuestra que has intentado analizar el problema y que los conceptos que aplicaste están correcto  ya que muchas veces al tener dudas lo que preguntas no necesariamente esta bien definido en tú mente.